# How to request commands in sequence?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently utilizing react-native and [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager) to create a ble application. The first app will send a list command to configure itself once it is connected. I'm sending these commands sequentially using Bitwise and a status number. But I believe it will become an issue and result in a significant command shift in the future.

Here is the sample code:

```
const RequestStatus = () => {
 resetAllConfiguration: 1,
 disableEchoConfiguration: 2, 
 lineFeedsConfiguration: 4,
 all: 7
}

const updateStatus = async (status) => {
 if ((status & RequestStatus.resetAllConfiguration) !== RequestStatus.resetAllConfiguration){
  return RequestStatus.resetAllConfiguration + status;
 } else if ((status & RequestStatus.disableEchoConfiguration) !== RequestStatus.disableEchoConfiguration){
  return RequestStatus.disableEchoConfiguration + status;
 } else if ((status & RequestStatus.lineFeedsConfiguration) !== RequestStatus.lineFeedsConfiguration) {
  return RequestStatus.lineFeedsConfiguration + status;
 } else if ((status & RequestStatus.all) === RequestStatus.all) {
  return RequestStatus.all;
 }
}


const sendCommand = async (peripheralId, status) =>{
  if ((status & RequestStatus.resetAllConfiguration) !== RequestStatus.resetAllConfiguration) {
   send('ATZ');
  } else if ((status & RequestStatus.disableEchoConfiguration) !== RequestStatus.disableEchoConfiguration) {
   send('ATEO');
  } else if ((status & RequestStatus.lineFeedsConfiguration) !== RequestStatus.lineFeedsConfiguration) {
   send('AT L1');
 }
```

After a few days of research, I found several approaches:

1. Function Chaining
2. Chain of Repository

I'm asking a question here, does anyone have a good solution to help me?

Thanks!!!